# QGIS autoreducing the length of the line

Tags: qgis

I have generated the grid and I would like to have my lines shorter.

[image]

I want them to match the last horizontal line
I tried splitting with lines, but it didn't work.

I don't want to reduce them one by one. Is there any quick solution for it?

Comment: how did you generate the gird? could you adjust that

Comment: Depending on how you made the grid and your future use of it, you could use one of the split lines tools (base QGIS, SAGA or Whitebox) and then easily select and delete all the lines that extend beyond your desired last cell with the select tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the tool `Vector Geometry -> Polygonize` on the line grid. If needs be, convert back to lines after.

[image]